# security of a const static struct object in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, static, constants

I am new to C programming and I am working on some project where I have to share lots of information between different source files .

In one source file I declare and initialize a variable of a specific struct , and In other file I need to use a pointer to that variable , to access the information inside it , but not to change it.

1. this variable CANNOT be changed anywhere else in my code .
2. this variable CANNOT be global , it has to be static .

code :

```
//file 1 :

typedef struct {
    bool (*decodeParameters)(void* interface, uint8_t command, uint16_t parameters[]);
    bool value;
} i_actuator_t;

static const i_actuator_t iActuator = {
    decodeActuatorParameters,  //pointer to a function in the same file 1
    false
};        //this variable has to be protected so it cannot be edited anywhere else , and it cannot be global .

i_actuator_t* getActuatorInterface (void) = {
    return &iActuator;
}
```

and in `file 2`, I want to do something like this :

```
i_actuator_t* iActuatorPTR = getActuatorInterface();
```

is a `static const` variable the right thing to do here ?
is there a better solution ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer your function returns should be marked `const` as well. So should the variables that use this return value.